# Create a `sonoma` tag

Tags: discussion, tags

As the new macOS version is announced (macOS 14 Sonoma), I suggest we create a tag for it.

Previous macOS versions have their own tags, Sonoma should have its own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to create a tag until someone asks a question where it's very relevant. Since we focus on practical questions, most questions will be closed as speculation based until things ship. So the Sonoma beta will proceed like all the other betas we have on site. Likely a full tag, then it becomes a synonym very quickly as needed.

Every macOS question needs the macOS tag, so there's a very short window of time (year or two) when the named / numbered tags are relevant.

Until Apple ships the vision hardware, that tag should be vaporware like the product.

Comment: Or when they sell one.  That thing is half the price of an entry level Mac Pro.

Comment: I was thinking for a business, I'd pay up to 10k for that kit if everything hit as well as possible and we truly could use macOS on it as an AirPlay display. Time will tell if the 2 hours on battery is a stretch - exciting times for software / input / sensor / AR/VR hardware... @Allan The $3500 price point is steep for vaporware or not being able to kick the tires or have deep research into how it will ship.

Comment: There's also a technical limitation on the SE tagging system though: tags cannot exist without questions, and tags without questions will be cleaned up daily by the system.